# why is my script sending a message to only one recipient in a MYSQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, forms, attachment

So i have this code that works perfectly without the 'file attachment' and sends messages typed in a html to all recipients in a MYSQL DB but when i do slot in the attachment codes, the mail gets sent but to only one recipient. Please help me out :)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

<?

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "mypass") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("mydb");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

$email = $row["email"];
$strSubject = $_POST["txtSubject"];
$strMessage = nl2br($_POST["txtDescription"]);

//*** Uniqid Session ***//
$strSid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$strHeader = "";
$strHeader .= "From: ".$_POST["txtFormName"]."<".$_POST["txtFormEmail"].">\nReply-To: ".$_POST["txtFormEmail"]."";

$strHeader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$strSid."\"\n\n";
$strHeader .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";

$strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$strHeader .= $strMessage."\n\n";
}
//*** Attachment ***//
if($_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"] != "")
{
    $strFilesName = $_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"];
    $strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["fileAttach"]["tmp_name"]))); 
    $strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
    $strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n"; 
    $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
    $strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n\n";
    $strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";
}


$flgSend = @mail($email,$strSubject,null,$strHeader);  // @ = No Show Error //

if($flgSend)
{
    echo "Task Complete. Your emails are being forwareded to your clients";
}
else
{
    echo "Error!!! Task incomplete. Please contact website maintainer.";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're setting `$email` inside your `while` clause - but only the final value will be saved at the end of the loop. I can't see how this could be sending email to multiple people to start with....

Comment: It works. I only mess up the code when i try adding the file attachment codes. so the code is all distorted for now. but without attachment codes, it sends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending the email within your while loop.

```
$strHeader .= $strMessage."\n\n";
} //This is the end of your while loop
//*** Attachment ***//
if($_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"] != "")
{
```

So your code should look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

<?

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "mypass") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("mydb");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

$email = $row["email"];
$strSubject = $_POST["txtSubject"];
$strMessage = nl2br($_POST["txtDescription"]);

//*** Uniqid Session ***//
$strSid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$strHeader = "";
$strHeader .= "From: ".$_POST["txtFormName"]."<".$_POST["txtFormEmail"].">\nReply-To: ".$_POST["txtFormEmail"]."";

$strHeader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$strSid."\"\n\n";
$strHeader .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";

$strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$strHeader .= $strMessage."\n\n";
//********************* This is the old end of while loop}
//*** Attachment ***//
if($_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"] != "")
{
    $strFilesName = $_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"];
    $strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["fileAttach"]["tmp_name"]))); 
    $strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
    $strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n"; 
    $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
    $strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n\n";
    $strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";
}


$flgSend = @mail($email,$strSubject,null,$strHeader);  // @ = No Show Error //

if($flgSend)
{
    echo "Task Complete. Your emails are being forwareded to your clients";
}
else
{
    echo "Error!!! Task incomplete. Please contact website maintainer.";
}

} // New end of while loop
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) but im still not getting you :p as in what should i do? sorry man, im so new to php. and yes, it is the last email in the table

Answer (score 2):

your email sending code is outside of the loop

move it inside below:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) but im still not getting you :p please show me the change in the code itself